# Understanding return value optimization from a factory method and static variable assignment (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

In a library I have a class A that's created and filled in a factory method of a class C. The returned object is then assigned to a static member var in class B. My problem is that return value optimization doesn't seem to kick in, at least in Visual Studio, it works as expected in XCode (with clang). What happens is that the d-tor of class A is called **before** the defined move assignement operator is used. In the d-tor I free some memory in A and hence after that the data is no longer valid.

```
class A {
public:
  A();
  A(const A &other);
  A(const A &&other);

  A& operator = (const A &other);
  A& operator = (const A &&other);
};

class B {
private:
  static A _a;
  struct Initializer {
    Initializer();
  };
  static Initializer _init;
};
```

and

```
B::Initializer::Initializer() {
  C c;
  _a = c.factoryMethod();
}

B::Initializer B::_init;
```

The factory method is quite simple:

```
A C::factoryMethod() {
  A a;
  ....
  return a;
}
```

On `return a` the copy constructor of A is called, followed by the d-tor. After that the move operator is triggerd (on assignment of the result to _a in B).

That is quite the opposite of what RVO is supposed to do. There should never be a copy (and hence a destruction, except when B is deleted). So, why's that not working as expected?

**Update**

After some trial and error I found a solution that works both in Visual Studio and XCode. However, since this question is about understanding how this is supposed to work (and why it doesn't in my case), I'm still interested in a good answer. What I did to solve my problem was to remove the copy constructor entirely, so it's never called actually.

The behavior of the two compilers is still different. VS uses the move constructor, while XCode does not, but requires that it is defined, no matter what. And the other strange effect is that I now have 2 moves in VS (the move constructor and after that a move assignment when I assign to the static member var). In XCode there is only the move assignment.

Comment: First, `A(const &&other);` is not valid syntax and shouldn't compile. Second, a move constructor normally takes a non-const rvalue reference. You probably meant `A(A&& other);` Similarly with assignment operator.

Comment: Seems to [work for me](http://rextester.com/KUY47394). I don't see the problem.

Comment: Yes, the syntax was wrong (I updated it). But for your live example: as I wrote in seems to depend on the compiler. Yes, it works as intended in XCode (clang), it's Visual Studio that makes problems. The `return a` ends up in the copy constructor, not in the move constructor, followed by a d-tor call from the same place, then the move assignment follows, when the return value is assigned to the static var. It's crazy. Btw. const or not doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: Ok, confirmed, that small example works, even in VS. I can even replace class A with my real class and it still works. It seems the class containing the factory method plays a role here. When I change the small example to the original factory method things start working wrong again.

Comment: Well, if you'd like further assistance, you'd have to produce an MCVE that actually demonstrates whatever problem you think you are still having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static A _a;
```

This is a static member variable. Therefore, it will be initialized *before `main`*. It already holds an object. Therefore, `_a = c.factoryMethod();` cannot elide the copy.

Copy elision can only happen when you are *initializing* the variable. It's already been initalized, so it must be copied into the already initialized variable.

Granted, this copy should take place via a call to `operator=`.

And no, the fact that your `_init` object is also static won't help. C++ defines the order of initialization for static objects within a C++ file, and that order is in declaration order. So `B::_a` is initialized first, then `B::_init`. So when `B::_init` runs, `B::_a` will already have been initialized. And reversing the order won't help, since you cannot assign to an object that hasn't started its lifetime yet.

If you really want to do complex initialization with elision, then you need to do it properly: when you declare your static member variable in the .cpp file:

```
A B::_a = []() {
  C c;
  return c.factoryMethod();
}()
```

---

The other thing you have to remember is that elision is *optional*. A compiler does not *have* to do it, and there's no way to force a compiler to do so.

Particularly for named variables. Even C++17's proposal for enforcing elision in certain cases only enforces it for non-named return values. With the proposed C++17 feature, and doing proper initialization with a lambda, then you're guaranteed that you would get, worst-case, one move constructor call.

Comment: I really thought this is it, but unfortunately, no that's no solution either. First, the small example from Igor works. Second, it works in clang. Both counter your claim that copy elision can only happen on initialization. And third, even with the lambda the copy constructor is still called when calling `return a` in my factory method.

Comment: @MikeLischke: See the additions to the answer.

Comment: The optional RVO is indeed a problem, if you rely on it. I have a number of class instances to delete in my class A, which obviously makes the copy invalid (if the copy c-tor or assignment is called). The const in the move constructor doesn't influence the search for it btw, neither in VS nor in XCode. However it has an important side effect: moving members fails and hence you have the same situation as with a copy constructor. So indeed, no const please :-)

Comment: Btw: I like your lambda init. Much nicer than the static struct init.